# Conversion of shell script to python script

Tags: python, shell

Say I have the following HTML script:

```
<head>$name</head>
```

And I have the following shell script which replaces the variable in the HTML script with a name

```
#/bin/bash
report=$(cat ./a.html)
export name=$(echo aakash)
bash -c "echo \"$report\""
```

This works.

Now I have to implement the shell script in Python so that I am able to replace the variables in the HTML file and output the replaced contents in a new file. How do I do it?

An example would help. Thanks.

Comment: If you can write it in `bash` you can convert it to `python` and test that... probably should have posted your python attempt first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
with open('a.html', 'r') as report:
    data = report.read()
data = data.replace('$name', 'aakash')
with open('out.html', 'w') as newf:
    newf.write(data)
```

Comment: Cool...Even I figured out that this is the only way....templates wont do since they require substitution of all variables at once, while I want them to replace one at a time

Comment: @user2359303: And, if you want to change only the first occurence, you can change `data.replace('$name', 'aakash')` to `data.replace('$name', 'aakash', 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're after a templating engine, but if you wanted a straight forward, no thrills, built into the standard library, here's an example using [string.Template](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template):

```python
from string import Template

with open('a.html') as fin:
    template = Template(fin.read())

print template.substitute(name='Bob')
# <head>Bob</head>
```

I thoroughly recommend you read the docs especially regarding escaping identifier names and using `safe_substitute` and such...

Comment: But this will require substituting all the variables at once. I want to substitute them one at a time.

Comment: @user2359303 to be fair - that wasn't ascertainable from your question and makes no sense - what is the reason you only want to/have to replace one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could save your html template like:

```
from string import Template
with open('a.html') as fin:
    template = Template(fin.read())
```

Then if you want to substitute variables one at a time, you need to use safe_substitute and cast the result to a template every time. This wont return a key error even when a key value is not specified.

Something like:

```
new=Template(template.safe_substitute(name="Bob"))
```

After this , the new template is new , which needs to be modified again if you would want.